# HTML Script RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML script that's being tested against the following regular expression, and I dont get how to translate it:
((.+<"br" /> (\n){3}.+\n.+*)

The regex has the br without the quotations that I added, but without the quotations StackOverflow wouldn't format the regex properly

Comment: i am unable to understand your issue exactly

Comment: Recheck the question. I fixed the regex. The problem is to look at some text from a book, and create the according HTML script for it. And the script is being tested against the above regex, which i don't understand

Comment: Could you use the SO facility for adding code to your question and also describe more what you are doing? The wording in your question implies it’s HTML that is being tested, the wording in your comment implies it’s the other way round.

Comment: Yea i have created an HTML page that's full of paragraphs, paragraph breaks, and headers. The HTML page is built to display text from a textbook. That HTML page is being tested, and the regex of ((.+<br /> (\n){3}.+\n.+*) is being ran during the test of the HTML page, and I don't understand how to translate this regex and fix my HTML to operate under the regex

Comment: It's invalid, there's a missing `)`.

Comment: Can anyone translate the regular expression?